# Failed assertion: line 5540 pos 12: '_children.contains(child)': is not true. Not able to pop a route and go back to previous screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on a screen A which let the user go to screen B , Now in screen B I have a back button which has Navigator,pop(context) when pressed . 
        But this keeps throwing this error "

> Failed assertion: line 5540 pos 12: '_children.contains(child)': is
>   not true.

" , whenever I press the back button.

```
class CustomAppBarWithoutSliver extends StatelessWidget
implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  var leftIcon;
  var rightIcon;
  var appBarText;
  var rightIconIsCart = false;
  var replaceRightIcon = false;
  var rightIconOnPressCallbackFunction;
  Widget replacedRightWidget;
  CustomAppBarWithoutSliver(
      {this.leftIcon,
      this.rightIcon,
      this.appBarText,
      this.rightIconIsCart,
      this.rightIconOnPressCallbackFunction,
      this.replaceRightIcon,
      this.replacedRightWidget});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    if (!rightIconIsCart) {
      rightIcon = Icons.search;
    }
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Color(appBarColor),
      title: (replaceRightIcon != null && replaceRightIcon == true)
          ? replacedRightWidget
          : Text('$appBarText', style: TextStyle(color: Color(textColor))),
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          leftIcon,
          color: Color(textColor),
        ),
        onPressed: () => (Navigator.pop(context)),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        (replaceRightIcon != null && replaceRightIcon == true)
            ? IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.cancel,
                ),
                onPressed: () => (rightIconOnPressCallbackFunction()),
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              )
            : IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  rightIcon,
                  color: Color(textColor),
                ),
                onPressed: () => (rightIconIsCart
                    ? Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyCartPage()))
                    : rightIconOnPressCallbackFunction()),
              )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement preferredSize
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

> So the above code returns a APPBAR , which contains a back button on left and Cart button on the right .
>   [Screen A Appbar Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IdEA.png)

After clicking on the right Icon , I move to screen B , where I have back button , which uses the same code above for building appBar .

so to build the appBar in screen B , I use the below code

```
return Scaffold(
appBar: CustomAppBarWithoutSliver(
    rightIcon: Icons.shopping_cart,
    leftIcon: Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
    appBarText: "",
    rightIconIsCart: false,
    rightIconOnPressCallbackFunction: this.rightIconHandleClick,
    replaceRightIcon: replaceRightIcon,
    replacedRightWidget: replacedRightWidget,
  ),
  body: CustomPaint( . . . .
```

which gives me this UI .
[Screen B AppBar Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnTXt.png)

> Now if I press this back Button , I get this error Failed assertion: line 5540 pos 12: '_children.contains(child)': is not true
>   [Error image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Eo7.jpg)

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please post some code.  This is pretty much impossible to make any intelligent guesses about without some code.

Comment: Can you drop your code?

Comment: Yeah sorry ! I have added the code and related images now .